# How many grams of acetic acid are present in 2.80 L of this vinegar?

Tags: physical-chemistry, concentration

> A vinegar sample is found to have a density of $1.006 \mathrm{\frac{g}{mL}}$ and to contain $8.7~\%$ acetic acid by mass. How many grams of acetic acid are present in $\pu{2.80L}$ of this vinegar?

I multiplied: $$\left(\frac{1.006~\mathrm{g}}{\mathrm{ml}}\right)\cdot \left(\frac{1000~\mathrm{ml}}{1~\mathrm{L}}\right)\cdot 2.80~\mathrm{L} = 2816.8~\mathrm{g}$$

I then converted $8.7~\%$ into $0.087$ and multiplied it into $2816.8$, to get the answer $245~\mathrm{g}$.

Am I correct?

Comment: Please add what you have attempted towards solving the problem into the body of your question.  For more information, see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) for how to ask homework questions. Thanks!

Comment: (you've done this very well in your other questions so far, so if you could do the same with this one, that would be great)

Comment: Can you tell me if I am on the right track?

Comment: Yes, I get the same answer as you.

Comment: @JohnSnow I appreciate you working hard in editing the questions with MathJax. I would appreciate it even more, if you would have a look at this [meta](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/443/4945) post, specifically the section about units and variables.

Answer (score 2):

Your math and stoichiometry are correct.
$2.80L*(\frac{1000 ml}{1 L})*(\frac{1.006 g}{ ml})*8.7$%$=245g \checkmark$